# AmplitudaResultJNI does not work on release build app

Tags: android

i get this message error when i build my app in release mode.

No pending exception expected: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no "Ljava/lang/String;" field "amplitudes" in class "Llinc/com/amplituda/AmplitudaResultJNI;" or its superclasses.
But app correctly works on Dev build. What should i do?

gradle file

```
implementation 'com.github.lincollincol:amplituda:2.1.2'
```

proguard-rules.pro

```
-keep class linc.com.amplituda.** { *; }
```

Thanks